# Love2d - How to make text clickable

Tags: text, lua, mouse, clickable, love2d

I have a simple text and I want it to quit when I click the text. sorry new to love2d

```
quit = love.graphics.print( "Quit", 450,375)

function love.mousepressed(quit)
  love.event.quit()
end
```

Comment: what happens? does your mousepressed get called? does the event.quit() execute?

Comment: sorry I answered it. I was being stupid

Answer (score 1):

```
function love.update(dt)
    function love.mousepressed( x, y)   
        if x > 440 and x < 540 and y > 380 and y < 410 then 
            love.event.quit()
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Warning! This redefines `love.mousepressed` every frame. Keep callbacks flat, and don't nest them.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a [Text](https://love2d.org/wiki/Text) object instead of using `love.graphics.print`. You can then query its [width](https://love2d.org/wiki/Text:getWidth) and [height](https://love2d.org/wiki/Text:getHeight) in your check and display it using `love.graphics.draw`. The code might look something like this:

```
function love.draw ()
  love.graphics.draw(quit.text, quit.x, quit.y)
end

function love.load ()
  local font = love.graphics.getFont()
  quit = {}
  quit.text = love.graphics.newText(font, "Quit")
  quit.x = 450
  quit.y = 375
end

function love.mousepressed (x, y, button, istouch)
  if x >= quit.x and x <= quit.x + quit.text:getWidth() and
     y >= quit.y and y <= quit.y + quit.text:getHeight() then
    love.event.quit()
  end
end
```